# Zend PDF Draw A Curved Line

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, draw

I'm currently trying to draw an angle line on a zend pdf drawing. Will try to explain as much as i know about it.
[image]

The code i have so far for the line and arrows is as following:

```
$this->drawArrow($pdf, $xStart + 58.5, $yStart,1, 270); //bottom left  arrow
$this->drawArrow($pdf, $xStart + $leftRake, $yStart + ($leftRake/     tan(deg2rad(abs($leftRake)))) ,1, 157); //top left  arrow
$pdf->drawCircle($xStart, $yStart, 58.5, 0, deg2rad(90 - abs($leftRake)), $fillType); //left angle line
```

The draw arrow is a function i created:

```
@param object $pdf The page to draw on
     * @param integer $x Page coordinate for arrow
     * @param integer $y Page coordinate for arrow
     * @param float $scale Default size 1
     * @param integer $angle Arrow angle 90 = up, 180 = right, 270 = down etc
     *
     * @return $pdf Page returned with arrow
     *
     */
    drawArrow($pdf, $x, $y, $scale = 1, $angle)

This is the function for drawCircle:
6.  * Method signatures:
7.  * drawCircle($x, $y, $radius);
8.  * drawCircle($x, $y, $radius, $fillType);
9.  * drawCircle($x, $y, $radius, $startAngle, $endAngle);
10. * drawCircle($x, $y, $radius, $startAngle, $endAngle, $fillType);
11. *
12. *
13. * It's not a really circle, because PDF supports only cubic Bezier
14. * curves. But very good approximation.
15. * It differs from a real circle on a maximum 0.00026 radiuses (at PI/8,
16. * 3*PI/8, 5*PI/8, 7*PI/8, 9*PI/8, 11*PI/8, 13*PI/8 and 15*PI/8 angles).
17. * At 0, PI/4, PI/2, 3*PI/4, PI, 5*PI/4, 3*PI/2 and 7*PI/4 it's exactly
18. * a tangent to a circle.
19. *
20. * @param float $x
21. * @param float $y
22. * @param float $radius
23. * @param mixed $param4
24. * @param mixed $param5
25. * @param mixed $param6
26. * @return Zend_Pdf_Page
27. */
28. public function  drawCircle($x,
29.                             $y,
30.                             $radius,
31.                             $param4 = null,
32.                             $param5 = null,
33.                             $param6 = null);
```

The closest to a curved line is by using the draw circle function:
xstart and ystart variables is the corner pont (bottom left)
The $leftRake point is an angle line, the value is stored in my database.

For the drawCircle line, the start angle is the bottom line (0) and the end angle ideally should line up to the diagonal straight line (which it does in the image)

My problem is - i can't seem to get the top arrow to match up to the end angle line in the draw circle bit...Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow placement issue appears to be the trigonometry as the code looks broadly ok.  So currently where you have this line:

```
$this->drawArrow($pdf, $xStart + $leftRake, $yStart 
+ ($leftRake / tan(deg2rad(abs($leftRake)))) ,1, 157); //top left  arrow
```

It should read:

```
$this->drawArrow($pdf, $xStart + (58.5 * cos(deg2rad(abs(90 - $leftRake)))), $yStart 
+ (58.5 * sin(deg2rad(abs(90 - $leftRake)))) ,1, 157); //top left  arrow
```